# d3.js : get td value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom

I am new with d3.js 
The problem i am facing is that i am unsure of how to get the value of td.

html

```
<table class="table">
<thead><tr>
    <th>S No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Arun</td>
    <td>Positive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Mickey</td>
    <td>Negetive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Zack</td>
    <td>Positive</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I read the documentation on d3.js but i couldnt find the documentation on how can i retrieve data from the table . 
Let's say that i would want to append a div with background color (green) on Credit that has value of negetive , how could we achieve this

This is what i tried

```
let selection = d3.selectAll("tr")
console.log("Get Table " + selection)

let headerElement = selection.nodes()[0];
let output = selection.selectAll("td")
```

i tried to printout the value of selected column with console.log(output["0"][1])
but i am receving error.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since D3 v4 selections are objects, not arrays anymore, so you cannot treat them like you did in `output["0"][1]`.

The idiomatic way to loop a selection is using `selection.each`. For instance:

```js
const tds = d3.selectAll("td")
  .each(function() {
    console.log(d3.select(this).text());
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Arun</td>
      <td>Positive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Mickey</td>
      <td>Negetive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Zack</td>
      <td>Positive</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

If you don't want another selection, `d3.select(this).text()` is the same of `this.innerHTML`.

Therefore, you can use the same `each` to set the *"background color (green) on Credit that has value of negetive"*, as you said:

```js
const tds = d3.selectAll("td")
  .each(function() {
    d3.select(this).style("background-color", this.innerHTML === "Positive" ? "green" : null)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Arun</td>
      <td>Positive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Mickey</td>
      <td>Negetive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Zack</td>
      <td>Positive</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks , but this is selecting the whole row. If i were to select only the column , how can we achieve that ?

Comment: @user12521913 No, this is not selecting the whole row, it's selecting only the tds.

Comment: lets say we have 3 by 3 table . if i were to select second and second column . only one selected cell.